# update a dataframe column with new values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

df1 has fields `id` and `json`; df2 has fields `id`and `json`

`df1.count()` => 1200; `df2.count()` => 20

df1 has all the rows. df2 has an incremental update with just 20 rows.

My goal is to update df1 with the values from `df2`. All the ids of `df2` are in df1. But df2 has updated values(in the `json` field) for those same ids.

Resulting df should have all the values from `df1` and updated values from `df2`.

What is the best way to do this? - With the least number of joins and filters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this using one left join.

**Create Example DataFrames**

Using the sample data provided by @Shankar Koirala in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49443599/5858851).

```python
data1 = [
  (1, "a"),
  (2, "b"),
  (3, "c")
]
df1 = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data1, ["id", "value"])

data2 = [
  (1, "x"), 
  (2, "y")
]

df2 = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data2, ["id", "value"])
```

**Do a left join**

Join the two DataFrames using a left join on the `id` column. This will keep all of the rows in the left DataFrame. For the rows in the right DataFrame that don't have a matching `id`, the value will be `null`.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df1.alias('l').join(df2.alias('r'), on='id', how='left')\
    .select(
        'id',
         f.col('l.value').alias('left_value'),
         f.col('r.value').alias('right_value')
    )\
    .show()
#+---+----------+-----------+
#| id|left_value|right_value|
#+---+----------+-----------+
#|  1|         a|          x|
#|  3|         c|       null|
#|  2|         b|          y|
#+---+----------+-----------+
```

**Select the desired data**

We will use the fact that the unmatched `id`s have a `null` to select the final columns. Use [`pyspark.sql.functions.when()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.when) to use the right value if it is not null, otherwise keep the left value.

```python
df1.alias('l').join(df2.alias('r'), on='id', how='left')\
    .select(
        'id',
        f.when(
            ~f.isnull(f.col('r.value')),
            f.col('r.value')
        ).otherwise(f.col('l.value')).alias('value')
    )\
    .show()
#+---+-----+
#| id|value|
#+---+-----+
#|  1|    x|
#|  3|    c|
#|  2|    y|
#+---+-----+
```

You can sort this output if you want the `id`s in order.

---

**Using pyspark-sql**

You can do the same thing using a pyspark-sql query:

```python
df1.registerTempTable('df1')
df2.registerTempTable('df2')

query = """SELECT l.id, 
CASE WHEN r.value IS NOT NULL THEN r.value ELSE l.value END AS value 
FROM df1 l LEFT JOIN df2 r ON l.id = r.id"""
sqlCtx.sql(query.replace("\n", "")).show()
#+---+-----+
#| id|value|
#+---+-----+
#|  1|    x|
#|  3|    c|
#|  2|    y|
#+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to provide a slightly more general solution. What happens if the input data has 100 columns instead of 2? We would spend too much time making a coalesce of those 100 columns to keep the values on the right side of the left join.
Another way to solve this problem would be to "delete" the updated rows from the original df and finally make a union with the updated rows.

```
data_orginal = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "a"),
    (2, "b"),
    (3, "c")
], ("id", "value"))

data_updated = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "x"),
    (2, "y")
], ("id", "value"))

data_orginal.show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|    a|
|  2|    b|
|  3|    c|
+---+-----+

data_updated.show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|    x|
|  2|    y|
+---+-----+

data_orginal.createOrReplaceTempView("data_orginal")
data_updated.createOrReplaceTempView("data_updated")

src_data_except_updated = spark.sql(f"SELECT * FROM data_orginal WHERE id not in (1,2)")
result_data = src_data_except_updated.union(data_updated)

result_data.show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  3|    c|
|  1|    x|
|  2|    y|
+---+-----+
```

Notice that the query

> SELECT * FROM data_orginal WHERE id not in (1,2)

could be generated automatically:

```
ids_collect = spark.sql(f"SELECT id FROM data_updated").collect()
ids_list = [f"{x.id}" for x in ids_collect]
ids_str = ",".join(ids_list)
query_get_all_except = f"SELECT * FROM data_original WHERE id not in ({ids_str})"
```