# Union with an existing RDD which is a set in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Given a set `U`, which is stored in RDD named `rdd`.

What is the recommended way to merge any given RDD `rdd_not_set` and `rdd` such that the resultant `rdd` is also an set.

```
rdd = sc.union([rdd, U])
rdd = rdd.reduceBykey(reduce_func)
```

Ex: `rdd = sc.parallelize([(1,2), (2,3)])` and `rdd_not_set = sc.parallelize([(1,4), (3,4)])` and resultant `final_rdd = sc.parallelize([(1,4), (2,3), (3,4)])`

Naive solution is to perform `union` and then `reduceByKey` which would be very inefficient as `rdd` will be huge in size.

Comment: By `set`, you mean that the first element of the `tuple` is the primary key? So if there's a duplicated key in `rdd_not_set`, you want to update with the new value?

Comment: Related (for DataFrames): [How to update a pyspark dataframe with new values from another dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50295783/how-to-update-a-pyspark-dataframe-with-new-values-from-another-dataframe)