# How to overwrite two dataframe in get the result like below

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have two data frames DF1 and DF2 through pyspar. I want output like below:

**DF1**

```
Id|field_A   |field_B   |field_C |field_D
1 |cat       |12        |black   |1
2 |dog       |128       |white   |2
```

**DF2**

```
Id|field_A|field_B|field_C
1 |cat    |13     |blue
```

Output required:

**DF3**

```
Id|field_A|field_B|field_C|field_D
1 |cat    |13     |blue   |1
2 |dog    |128    |white  |2
```

I have tried through the join concept, but it's not working through the below joins.

> 'inner',  'outer',  'full',  'fullouter',  'full_outer',  'leftouter',
>   'left',  'left_outer',  'rightouter',  'right',  'right_outer', 
>   'leftsemi',  'left_semi', 'leftanti',  'left_anti',  'cross'

```
DF3 = DF2.join(DF1, DF1.ID == DF2.ID,"leftouter")
```

Comment: could you please format the code properly so I can try to help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [update a dataframe column with new values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49442572/update-a-dataframe-column-with-new-values)

Answer (score 0):

First , you must to declare alias to Dataframes:

```
val a = df1.as("a")
val b = df2.as("b")
```

Create an array with the columns that not updated

```
val columnsNotUpdated =
        Seq(col("a.Id").as("Id"), col("a.field_D").as("field_D"))
```

Create an array with the columns that updated , and use when to see if it crosses (b.Id is not null) with dataframe b and if it crosses, select the value of dataframe 'b'

```
 val columnsUpdated = a.columns
        .filter(x => !Array("Id", "field_D").exists(_ == x))
        .map(x =>
          when(col("b.Id").isNotNull, col(f"b.$x").as(x))
            .otherwise(col(f"a.$x").as(x)))
```

Finally , join with 'left_outer' and select the columns

```
a.join(b, col("a.Id") === col("b.Id"), "left_outer")
        .select(columnsNotUpdated.union(columnsUpdated): _*)
```

All code is :

```
val a = df1.as("a")
      val b = df2.as("b")

      val columnsNotUpdated =
        Seq(col("a.Id").as("Id"), col("a.field_D").as("field_D"))

      val columnsUpdated = a.columns
        .filter(x => !Array("Id", "field_D").exists(_ == x))
        .map(x =>
          when(col("b.Id").isNotNull, col(f"b.$x").as(x))
            .otherwise(col(f"a.$x").as(x)))

      a.join(b, col("a.Id") === col("b.Id"), "left_outer")
        .select(columnsNotUpdated.union(columnsUpdated): _*)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. let me try to convert in pyspark