# How to group unioned dataframe to combine same rows

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, group-by, pyspark, union

I have just unioned two dataframes in pyspark and instead of it combining the rows with the same dates, it stacked them on top of each other like so:

##### df1:

```
+----------+------------+--------------+
|      date| bounceCount|  captureCount|
+----------+------------+--------------+ 
|  20190518|           2|          null|
|  20190521|           1|          null|
|  20190519|           1|          null|
|  20190522|           1|          null|
+----------+------------+--------------+
```

##### df2:

```
+----------+-------------+-------------+
|      date| captureCount|  bounceCount|
+----------+-------------+-------------+ 
|  20190516|         null|            3|
|  20190518|         null|            2|
|  20190519|         null|            1|
|  20190524|         null|            5|
+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

##### union:

```
+----------+------------+--------------+
|      date| bounceCount|  captureCount|
+----------+------------+--------------+ 
|  20190518|           2|          null|
|  20190521|           1|          null|
|  20190519|           1|          null|
|  20190522|           1|          null|
|  20190516|        null|             3|
|  20190518|        null|             2|
|  20190519|        null|             1|
|  20190524|        null|             5|
+----------+------------+--------------+
```

I would like it to group it so that the rows with the same dates get combined with the correct `bounceCount` and `captureCount`:

```
+----------+------------+--------------+
|      date| bounceCount|  captureCount|
+----------+------------+--------------+ 
|  20190518|           2|             2|
|  20190521|           1|          null|
|  20190519|           1|             1|
|  20190522|           1|          null|
|  20190516|        null|             3|
|  20190524|        null|             5|
+----------+------------+--------------+
```

I have tried putting them together in different ways, and grouping the dataframe in different ways, but I cannot figure it. I will also be attaching this dataframe with several other columns, so I would like to know the best way to do this. Anyone know a simple way of doing this?

Comment: You want to do a `join`, not `union`.

Comment: See [What are the various join types in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990633/what-are-the-various-join-types-in-spark/54479858) and [update a dataframe column with new values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49442572/update-a-dataframe-column-with-new-values).

Comment: OR you can probably do a `groupBy` after the `union`, but the `join` is probably more efficient.

Comment: The column name of `df2` in the example is probably wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by outer join.

```
df = (
    df1.select('date', 'bounceCount')
    .join(
        df2.select('date', 'captureCount'),
        on='data', how='outer'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

Join(full) both dataframes and use [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce) function.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce

joining_condition = [df1.date == df2.date]

df1\
    .join(df2,joining_condition,'full')\
    .select(coalesce(df1.date,df2.date).alias('date')
            ,df1.bounceCount
            ,df2.bounceCount.alias('captureCount'))\
    .show()

#+--------+-----------+------------+
#|    date|bounceCount|captureCount|
#+--------+-----------+------------+
#|20190518|          2|           2|
#|20190519|          1|           1|
#|20190521|          1|        null|
#|20190524|       null|           5|
#|20190522|          1|        null|
#|20190516|       null|           3|
#+--------+-----------+------------+
```

I think columns of `df2` dataframe got interchanged. Please check. if that's the case change the column names in solution.